# VSCode shell task escaping single quotes

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

VSCode provides shell escaping when defining tasks.  I have tried the different mechanisms, and don't have a results that would work universally.

Given a test string:

```
hello 'world' (what's your name? --)
```

tasks.json has:

```
    {
        "label": "test",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo",
        "args":[
            {
                "value": ["${selectedText}"],
                "quoting": "escape"
            }

        ]
    },
```

With this approach, vscode has parsed the task to:

```
echo hello\ \'world\'\ (what\'s\ your\ name?\ --)
```

That's totally wrong. - not escaped, ) not escaped, and no quotes around the parameter.

I tried quoting="strong"

Now the task was parsed to:

```
 echo 'hello 'world' (what's your name? --)'
```

That's no good!  Now the single quotes in the string are in the way.

I've also tried changing value to ['${selectedText}'] - and in this case, we get

```
echo ''
```

It does not appear that we can get proper shell escaping out of the box.  I think I need to create a script internal to vscode and avoid the shell altogether.  What's the best way to proceed?

I am on Windows 10, WSL, bash, VSCode 1.55.1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with the stated original behavior. `echo hello\ \'world\'\ (what\'s\ your\ name?\ --)` is _not_ totally wrong. It's exactly the same string as `$'hello \'world\' (what's your name? --)'`, when parsed through an `eval` phase, which means that post-shell-eval, it turns into the string that as JSON would be described as `"hello 'world' (what's your name? --)"`.

Comment: ...if the real problem is that you're telling VS Code to escape things for `eval`, but there's no `eval` actually taking place, _that_ would make sense. But then, I don't use VS Code (still resent Microsoft funding SCO's anti-Linux efforts in the mid-2000s and unwilling to use anything they make), so can't repro firsthand.

Comment: I was looking to pipe SQL queries to psql on the terminal.  So I needed to make sure exactly the what's on the screen gets to the shell.  The first option would generate a bash error on -- and )

Comment: You're right -- the `(` and `)` should be escaped. (I don't see why the `--` would need to be).

Comment: You are right @CharlesDuffy ... for some reason i thought, bash hates dashes in strings. But vscode 'escape' needs to be modified.

Comment: Strings that _start_ with dashes have special handling sometimes (POSIX-specified rules documented at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02 are relevant), but that's typically downstream from bash itself and found in the utilities it runs. Anyhow, yes, I agree entirely; vscode escape should be fixed. In your shoes I might try to find a solution that doesn't require any shell escaping at all (passing a literal argument vector to the target process instead), but that's for someone who actually runs VSCode and can test other approaches to try to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution, and it works.  Hopefully, someone else will feel the happiness that it brought me. :-)

```
    {
        "label": "test",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo \"$(cat << 'HEREDOC' \n${selectedText}\nHEREDOC\n)\" ",
    }
```

This takes advantage of the HEREDOC mechanism that exists in bash.  Credit goes (a bit belatedly) to skztr in [this thread](https://qntm.org/bash) - posted in 2010!

This takes advantage of HEREDOC syntax bash supports:

```
<< 'TAG' 
stuff
TAG
```

allows stuff to be passed to bash completely unprocessed. It's important to note that the line breaks after << 'TAG'  and before the final TAG are required.  To make it work in the json files, I placed \n into the string, and that worked well since they will be passed to the shell, which will know what to do with them.

Finally, the quotation marks around the "command" value are required as well as the quotations around what's passed to echo. The inner set has to be escaped with ".  Thus we get

```
"command":  "echo \"...\""
```

Comment: Works only insofar as your `selectedText` doesn't contain a line with only `HEREDOC`. That's a significant limitation.

Comment: I suppose, using a longer randomly generated string like a uuid would be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

To offer a more robust alternative: Use an **aux. environment variable**, which *bypasses* any quoting/escaping concerns:

```json
{
  "label": "test",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "echo \"$__selectedText\"",
  "options": {
    "env": {
      "__selectedText": "${selectedText}"
    }
  }
}
```